# What does @include media-query mean in SASS?

Tags: sass, media-queries

I'm hacking some SASS code (I've never seen any SASS before, I've only used plain old CSS2 in the past) and feel like I don't really understand what does `@include media-query($variable)` mean. I've tried googling it but surprisingly it doesn't seem to find any kind of manual or example for this code. As far as I understand it is used to define a medium-specific rule to apply a different style when the web page is rendered on a mobile device and in fact this is what I need but I feel like I have to understand the exact meaning of the code to use it correctly.

Comment: Calling a mixin with the name media-query and a parameter with the name $variable

Comment: http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#mixins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```scss
@include media-query($variable)
```

is a mixin call.

you should have somewhere in your sass files a mixin declaration like this:

```scss
@mixin media-query($variable) {
    // ...
}
```